# Directly boot into my program that requires user input

Tags: boot, pi-zero, raspi-config

I have a project called "Sleepy Notes" where I can type early in the morning and record dreams, poems and crazy ideas.

Now since my program requires user input via the keyboard it cannot be run in the background using systemctl. I did some research and found that there is a mode to autologin into a text console, which you can see on the screenshot I found.

[image: boot option]

However, on my Raspberrypi I have no such option under Boot Options. I can only choose to boot into the Desktop or the CLI:

[image: no option]

How can I enable the "Auto-Login" mode on my Raspberrypi.

```
uname -a
Linux sleepynotes 4.19.97+ #1294 Thu Jan 30 13:10:54 GMT 2020 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You are running on old OS (~18 months old) but there is no fundamental difference between the options, neither of which will run a user program. Why do you even want to turn the Pi off?

Comment: Well Mister Dent @Milliways, I do not want to turn it off but in case there is an outage it has to boot into the program without my help. So I have to deactivate the user prompt after boot and directly start my program.

Comment: @Besi this appears to be a question about Linux ... you are reducing your chance of getting a good answer by limiting your search to the Raspberry Pi

Comment: @jsotola: I only partially agree. The `raspi-config` has an option that addresses exactly what I'm looking for. However, I might follow your advice and post this in the Unix forum.